# got error Positional parameter [1] is not registered with this procedure call when calling a stored procedure in a jpa repository

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to call a basic oracle pl/sql stored procedure that returns a string from table student (name , age , email). I am using named stored procedure annotations but i am getting an error when execute the logic. i would appreciate your help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_findemail (email OUT VARCHAR2)
IS 
BEGIN
    SELECT EMAIL INTO email FROM STUDENT WHERE ID=1;
END p_findemail;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Student")

@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name="p_findemail",
        procedureName = "p_findemail",
        parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(name="email" , mode = ParameterMode.OUT , type=String.class)
        }
        
    )
})


public class Student {
```

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student,Long>{     
    
    @Procedure(value = "p_findemail",                  
                name = "p_findemail",
                outputParameterName = "email")

    String findstudentbyid();      
    
}
```

and this is the error i am getting

ERROR 2864 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Positional parameter [1] is not registered with this procedure call; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Positional parameter [1] is not registered with this procedure call] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Positional parameter [1] is not registered with this procedure call
at org.hibernate.query.procedure.internal.ProcedureParameterMetadata.getQueryParameter(ProcedureParameterMetadata.java:141)

Comment: Naming parameters as columns is a *bad practice*. This: `SELECT EMAIL INTO email ...` looks *wrong*. I suggest you rename procedure's parameter to e.g. `p_email` and do `SELECT EMAIL INTO p_email ...`.  As of your Java stuff, I'm not good at it so I can't comment it.

Answer (score 1):

issue seems to be Spring-Data-JPA

```
[https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2188][1]
```

The fix which is working for me is:

Change out parameter to INOUT

```
  @StoredProcedureParameter(name="email" , mode = ParameterMode.INOUT ,
  type=String.class)
```

And the while calling your stored procedure from repository

```
 @Procedure(name = STORED_PROC_NAME)
  
 // email is passed as null
 String findstudentbyid(@Param("email") String email);
 
 and pass this email as null.
```

PS: You might have to use Map or String as your return type depending what your stored pro returns.

Comment: doesn't work for me